# MS Access VBA convert query output to Excel format but not saving anywhere

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I've been trying to use transfer spreadsheet methods but they appear to require an output path.

I just need to find out how to take a given query and simply "open up" an Excel file that contains the query output. I don't need the file actually saved anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can open up your file without saving it by creating an Excel instance (or grabbing an existing one) and using the `CopyFromRecordset` function of the `Excel.Range` object.

This assumes your data are in an ADO recordset. You need to have references to `Microsoft Excel XX.0 Object Library` and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library` (if you are using ADO. If you use DAO then use whatever DAO reference you need)

I use this to grab an an Excel app or create a new one is Excel is not open already. I use `WasANewInstanceReturned` to figure how I need to clean up the Excel resources at the end. (Obviously I don't want to quit Excel if it is being use by something else).

```
Function GetExcelApplication(Optional ByRef WasANewInstanceReturned As Boolean) As Excel.Application

    If ExcelInstanceCount > 0 Then
        Set GetExcelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        WasANewInstanceReturned = False
    Else
        Set GetExcelApplication = New Excel.Application
        WasANewInstanceReturned = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then grab that instance

```
Dim ApXL As Excel.Application, WasANewInstanceReturned as Boolean
Set ApXL = GetExcelApplication(WasANewInstanceReturned)
```

Add a workbook

```
Dim wbExp As Excel.Workbook
Set wbExp = ApXL.Workbooks.Add
```

Grab the first sheet

```
Dim wsSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
Set wsSheet1 = wbExp.Sheets(1)
```

Put your recordset's field names in the first row

```
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim col As Integer
col = 1
With wsSheet1 
For Each fld In rst.Fields
    .Cells(1, col).Value = fld.Name  'puts the field names in the first row
    End With
    col = col + 1
Next fld
End With
```

Then move the data just below the field names

```
wsSheet1 .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Voila! You have an excel file open, with your data that has not been saved anywhere!

I usually set `ApXL.ScreenUpdating = False` before doing any of this and `ApXL.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

I'll let you stitch this together for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The file **must** be saved somewhere for Excel to open it.
If the dataset is small enough, you can use copy/paste (no file here).  Otherwise, just use the %TEMP% folder for the file location.

---

Edit:
One simple way to get the TEMP folder is to use `=Environ("TEMP")`

Comment: How do I use the temp folder properly?

Answer (score 0):

I open and export a query from access to excel. First I created a worksheet in excel and saved it. Then I created a module in the vba part of Access (2013):

```
Option Compare Database


' Testtoexporttoexcel'

Function ExportQuerytoExcel()

On Error GoTo ExportQuerytoExcel_Err

' Exports the query to excel to a sheet named Nameofyoursheet

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "nameofyourquery", "yourPath:\nameofyourworkbook", False, "Nameofyour worksheet"


ExportQuerytoExcel_Exit:
    Exit Function

ExportQuerytoExcel_Err:

    MsgBox Error$

    Resume ExportQuerytoExcel_Exit

End Function

-----then add another function that says:

Option Compare Database

Function OpenExcelFromAccess()

'Opens Excel to the chart

 Dim MYXL As Object

 Set MYXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  With MYXL

  .Application.Visible = True

  .workbooks.Open "Yourpath:\nameofyourworkbook"

  End With

  'Application.Quit

End Function
```

---

hope this helps, this is my first time answering a question.
Aloha